# Is there a way to customize what a button looks like in C++?

Tags: c++, user-interface, button, ubuntu-10.04

I have programmed in HTML, Java, CSS, C++, VB, an Python.
I'm looking to make button that looks completely the way I want it to look!
Like in HTML+Java+CSS, I can do that very thing!
I'm using Netbeans IDE. I was about to just use OpenGL to do the GUI programming for my programs, since it is so hard to find information on customized GUIs.
 
I just want to learn how to make the image and give button functionality to it. I want to be able to make the shape, color, and effects (when clicked, hovered over, etc).

Oh, and I program in Ubuntu Linux!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try qt ...  http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have any GUI defined by the language, you usually have to use a library. Most GUI libraries allow you to do what you want, but the answer will differ. Just pick one (GTK+ and QT are the most popular in Linux) an ask again.

Comment: c++ is my preferred language. i have seen peoples programs made in c++ with nice gui's but i cant find any info on things like that! all i get is generic gui's from IDE programs.... like Netbeans, and Visual Studios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is a good idea, but you won't learn how it works, though it's not really important and far easier like that. Using C++ you will have libraries that respect the encapsulation principle, so you won't know at the first sight how do is work, just how to use it.

If you really want to code a button yourself, you can take a 2D drawing library such as SFML, with which you'll draw your button and handle events on it.

Comment: Well you can always take a toolkit/framework like Qt, subclass the button class and reimplement just the methods you need, while keeping the basic functionality that you want to work like the default behaviour, without having to reinvent the (square) wheel.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a custom button class for my app, we (the C++ developers) were given PNG images from the designer department. They are much better with tools like Photoshop then we developers. We just showed image1.PNG by default, image2.PNG when the mouse was over the button ("hover"), and image3.PNG when the mouse was over the button and pressed. Drawing? Not necessary.

Color is trivial for designers. Shape isn't hard either. PNGs are rectangular, but can be transparent. So rounded edges are just a matter of a few transparent pixels there.